# Python pytesseract to solve captcha

Tags: python-3.x, captcha

I'm trying to solve a captcha in python with pytesseract module. This is my code:

```
def captcha():
    image = cv2.imread('captcha.jpeg')

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    #gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 3)

    filename = "{}.png".format("temp")
    cv2.imwrite(filename, gray)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('temp.png'),
                                       config='--psm 8 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789abcdefghijkmnlopkrstuvwxyz')
    print('Captcha solved:' + text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    captcha()
```

And captchas are with this format:

[image: captcha]

The result calculated is: `Captcha solved:“Fates` when the result should be `182aa`